# Laravel 5 > Using monolog introspection processor

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5, monolog

I have configured Laravel 5 to use a custom logging configuration (default is way too simple). I've added monolog's [IntrospectionProcessor](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Processor/IntrospectionProcessor.php) to log the file name and line number of the log call.

The problem is that all lines get the same file and line number:

```
[2015-06-29 17:31:46] local.DEBUG (/home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php#201): Loading view...  [192.168.10.1 - GET /loans/create]
```

Is there a way to config the IntrospectionProcessor to print the actual lines and not the facade ones?

If I do `Log::getMonolog()->info('Hello');` it works and prints the correct file and line number... but I don't know how safe is to avoid calling the [Writer.writeLog function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php#L198) because it fires a log event (is it safe to not fire that event?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the expected functionality unless you're having the handler process the logs directly (check out the comments at the top of IntrospectionProcessor.php). My guess is you have a wrapper function around the logger and you're calling it from Writer.php -- BUT

If you look at the code for IntrospectionProcessor.php you'll see a bit of code on lines 81 to 87 that decides how to format that stack trace, and it still has access to the stack. If you bump the $i values for $trace[$i - 1] / $trace[$i] up one (aka $trace[$i]/$trace[$i + 1] respectively) you can 'climb' the stack back to  where you want.

It's important to note that the 'class' and 'function' parts of the trace need to be one level of the stack higher than the 'file' and 'line.'

On a personal (plz dont mod me bruhs) note, I'd like to see functionality to include a stack offset when throwing the log in. I know what function I want to blame if an error shoots out when I write the error_log('ut oh') but I might(will) forget that by the time the 'ut oh' comes.

Comment: Yes, the main problem is Laravel's way of wrapping the log object. I ended up calling it directly and so far I haven't had any problems at all.

Comment: Glad to hear you're set! Another feature (I didn't realize this until today) of the IntrospectionProcessor is a parameter for classes/functions you want to skip in the trace. Fickle if you change function names, but definitely useful to get around the wrapper!

Answer (score 4):

(Only tried in Laravel 4.2!)

When pushing the Introspection Processor to Monolog it is possible to give an skipClassesPartial array as second parameter in the IntrospectionProcessor contructor. With this array it is possible to skip the Laravel Illuminate classes and the logger logs the class calling the log method.

```
$log->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor(Logger::DEBUG, array('Illuminate\\')));
```

also see: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Processor/IntrospectionProcessor.php

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd give a quick update because it's pretty easy to get this done now.

I haven't tried with Laravel but My own logging mechanism is within a `LoggingService` wrapper class. As such the introspection was only giving details about the service rather than the caller.

after reading Matt Topolski's answer, I had a look in the `IntrospectionProcessor.php`. the constructor looks like this:

```
__construct($level = Logger::DEBUG, array $skipClassesPartials = array(), $skipStackFramesCount = 0)
```

All I had to do was add the processor like this:

```
log->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor(Logger::DEBUG, array(), 1));
```